# RobotFramework - Close Browser - WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, robotframework, selenium2library

I am getting following error on last step of all my tests - because of that, all Test Cases are marked as failed.

Test Example:

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation  TEST Close Browser
Library  SeleniumLibrary

*** Test Cases ***
Google test
  Open Browser  about:blank  chrome
  Maximize Browser Window
  Go To  https://google.com
  Close Browser
```

All steps executes correctly - even the last step closes browser, but it is throwing this error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: invalid session id
(Driver info: chromedriver=70.0.3538
.16(16ed95b41bb05e565b11fb66ac33c660b721f778)
,platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64)
```

I am using latest chromedriver and all of my robotframework dependecies are also updated.

Can someone please help me get rid of that error?

Comment: Why did you use Open Browser and then Go To as well? I think only use one of them is enough.